# FusionChart Dynamic rendering Charts

Tags: jquery, ajax, render, fusioncharts

I'm trying to recreate a dashboard to learn correctly how to use FusionCharts.

[This is the dashboard](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dashboards/real-estate/) I'm replicating. If you notice, every time you navigate through the tabs the Charts will re-render.

In my site (http://sisfacil.cl/plantilla/)

Charts will only render once, the first time you change to any tab or change any select input(which is intended to do anyways as it changes the chart's data).

**I want to achieve the same re-rendering on tab change as in the dashboard**

Right now I render the Charts two ways;

The first one is refering to a .js in the index.php that builds and render pretty much every chart in the page, this charts have static data so they're built like this:

```
var myChart = new FusionChart (
//structure and static data here*
).render();
```

The second one is by sending parameters through Ajax to another .php that retreives data from a MySQL DataBase that I jsonEncode after, which are in the same .js called above. This to change chart's data on selects and looks like this:

```
$('#sel1sbmn2chart2').on('change', function(){
    var x = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/gastoDinamico.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {selYear: x},
        success: function(data){
            myChart.setChartData(data, "json");
        }
    });
});
```

Also I've attached onClick events with jquery to re-render the First chart on the page which is in the Presupuestos/Ventas tab. Done the same way the code above.

This is akwardly working as it have some weird behaviors rendering the chart again. Some times it will re-render the Chart from 0 (meaning, the same way the FusionCharts dashboard I'm trying to replicate does) Others, you will see the Chart rendered (in cache) and then re-rendering. And other times the chart will render with other resolution, smaller (I have the resolution set to 600x400 and the small one looks like a pre-set resolution or something).

I've tried other aproaches to this problem like using the .dispose() method before render again but I can't get it to work (error: dispose() is not a function/duplicated ID chart/cannot find DOM element to render/etc)

Also, researching on the internet I've found that everyone have the opposite problem. Charts dynamically rendering on tab change..

I think most of the code you can look at it in the sourse Code of my webpage or else if you need any other specific piece of code I can edit my OP.

**How can I make the charts dynamically render on tab change?**

Can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Wild Guess! This is possibly not with FusionCharts but with the tab component you are using. can't open your site to investigate further.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap tabs.. maybe [this url](http://www.sisfacil.cl/plantilla/) will work?